# Ubuntu 14.04 Low Resolution with DVI-D Monitor and Nvidia geforce 550 Ti

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

I have a Dell ST2320L Monitor and Nvidia geforce GTX 550 Ti Graphics card. I have connected the monitor on the DVI-D port. After fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 I was getting 640x480 resolution, I installed nvidia-352 proprietary driver then I started getting a blank screen on boot.

So I purged the nvidia-352 driver and installed nvidia-340 proprietary driver and it started showing me 800x600 resolution but no other optional resolution. As per the monitor size I should get 1920x1080.

I went through some solutions mentioned for other questions in this forum, like manually adding display modes to xorg.conf or by using xrandr but those solutions did not work for me.

Here is the xorg log that is getting generated - http://pasted.co/738cdee6

I think the monitor connected with the DVI-D port is not getting detected correctly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the EDID data returned by your monitor is not correct. This data is how the monitor communicates its preferred settings to the graphics card.

There are several ways to fix this :

**try a different cable** - if you have another one its worth a try , also try your cable on another system.

**define your monitor settings in your xorg.conf** - add a monitor section and specify the refresh rates , modelines won't help here.

**supply an EDID in a file** -  if you have access to a another of these monitors you can save the EDID to a file and quote it in your xorg.conf.

Comment: Thanks for the help, took me a lot of time to zero down that the DVI-D cable was not in its best condition, replacing it fixed it.